# Running xcodebuild on command line, where to view logs?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I want to view the log when building an xcode (4.5) project from the command-line, since the output in the command-line window itself is too long and messy. Is there a standard place the logs would go, I can't seem to find them?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Like all command line tools, output goes to standard output and error goes to standard error. By default this is your command line terminal. Use piping and/or redirection if you want them somewhere else. Check your command line interpreter documentation for more info (probably you are using bash, so check `man bash`).

Comment: oh ok; I'd thought maybe it auto-logged to a file somewhere.

Comment: Internal compiler problems may (or not) be logged to the system logging facility. Normal compiler "response", which I suppose is what you are looking for, is written to stdout and stderr. You can redirect either or both to a file. You can also use pipes to make standard output become standard input of another command. This allows you to "pipe" it to `more` or `less` for easy reading (not really needed in the era of scrolling terminal windows). You may also have a look at the command `tee` (pipe to `tee` so you get both the normal "to the terminal" output and save the data to a file.

Answer (score 10):

There are logs in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` -- you'll have to figure out which sub folder is for your build, but in there is `Logs/Build/UUID.xcactivitylog`

If you rename that file to a .zip and unzip, there's a text file log in there of the build.

Comment: This logs are not readable. I am not able to find why build is getting failed. Which method or piece of code is problematic?

Comment: `gzcat _name_.xcactivitylog |  tr '\r' '\n' | less`